# Are these sentences grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses

Are both of these sentences grammatical?

> It was starting raining.
>   He was contemplating creating a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammaticaly correct, as evidenced by the fact that you can say “it starts raining” and “he contemplates creating a problem”. The phrases you wrote are just the corresponding progressive tense.

Of course, ***as a matter of style***, it is awkward to have those two *-ing* forms one right after the other. So, people would usually write it in other ways to avoid this, including “it was starting to rain”.